# Java - Creating an Undefined Array

Tags: java, arrays, undefined

I'm looking to create an array that will be able to change size over time because the size of the array is unpredictable and I don't want to create a huge random number that will waste memory so every time a button is pressed I need the array to grow by one.

```
private String[][] lyricLineInfo = new String[x][5];
```

In the place of x is where the array must grow upon the button push and 5 is a constant. So I need the x button to grow by one without overflowing. Can I do it by using something like this?

```
lyricLineInfo[lyricLineInfo.length + 1][4] = fieldLyrics.getText();
```

Anyways thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd better use an ArrayList instead of an Array.

Comment: So you want an array that needs to be copied into a new array EVERY time you add an element? Why not just use an ArrayList and be done with it?

Comment: If the second dimension acts like switch, which determines type of content in the first dimension, then you should implement class with problem specific fields instead. This reduces array/list dimensions by one. example: `LyricLineInfo[] lyricLineInfo;` then `lyricLineInfo[lineNumber].setLineText(fieldLyrics.getText());` more readable than _magic index_ 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList<String[]>` (see the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). It will grow automatically. (It uses an internal array that doesn't actually grow by just 1 when it needs to grow. Since growing is an expensive operation, it grows by some larger amount so it can absorb a few more items before having to grow again.)

**EDIT**

For example, here's how you could recode the two lines of your original post:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<String[]>();

lyricLineInfo.add(fieldLyrics.getText());
```

The second line assumes that `fieldLyrics.getText()` returns a `String[]`. If I misunderstood your intent and it returns a String, then you could do the following:

```
String[] nextStrings = new String[5];
nextStrings[4] = fieldLyrics.getText();
lyricLineInfo.add(nextStrings);
```

If the second index isn't always 5 long, you can also have an ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lyricLineInfo
    = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Then you could `lyricLineInfo.add(new ArrayList<String>());` to extend the array.

**EDIT 2**

@clankfan1 - In your comment, you asked how to do a particular operation. Let's say we're using the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` structure. It would go something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
line.add("true");
line.add("true");
line.add("0.0");
line.add("5.0");
line.add("First Line");
lyricLineInfo.add(line);
line = new ArrayList<String>(); // don't use clear(): need a new object here
line.add("false");
line.add("false");
line.add("5.0");
line.add("10.0");
line.add("Second Line");
lyricLineInfo.add(line);

String secondLineTitle = lyricLineInfo.get(1).get(4); // will be "Second Line"
```

Obviously, this logic is amenable to being put into a separate method.

**EDIT 3**

If you need the elements of `lyricLineInfo` to be of type `String[]`, it is vital that each element be a distinct array. Here are a few coding styles for adding elements:

```
ArrayList<String[]> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] line = { "true", "true", "0.0", "5.0", "First Line" };
lyricLineInfo.add(line);
// now for a second style:
line = new String[5];
line[0] = "false";
line[1] = "false";
line[2] = "5.0";
line[3] = "10.0";
line[4] = "Second Line";
lyricLineInfo.add(line);
// and a third style:
lyricLineInfo.add(new String[] {
    "false", "true", "10.0", "15.0", "Third Line"
});

String secondLineTitle = lyricLineInfo.get(1)[4]; // will be "Second Line"
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ArrayLists since I'm still learning java how would I replace the current array I'm using with the ArrayList and what are the differences between arrays and ArrayLists?

Comment: @clankfan1 - The biggest difference is that instead of subscripting you use `get` and `set` (and `add` to append). (Of course, you'll also have to change all the relevant declarations and `new` allocations.)

Comment: OK so if I'm understanding correctly I will still create a 1D array because my second index is for sure a constant of 5 and then with my array I will place it into an array list which will let me extend my first index to whatever I need it to then I can set values for certain items in my arraylist. I'm pretty sure it does but, does the arraylist hold values? For example if I needed to access and index on an arraylist could I pass in any value and then pass in a value for my array to get a value back.

Comment: @clankfan1 - I'm not sure what you're asking. The arraylist holds arrays of String. You can access a String[] using `lyricLineInfo.get(index)`. If you assign an element of that array (e.g., `lyricLineInfo.get(index)[4] = "hello"`), that will be automatically key in the arraylist, because the String[] is still an element of the list. Does that help?

Comment: Here's what I mean. So my program using an array would would assign the line value lyricLineInfo[ here ][] and the info stored for that line lyricLineInfo[][ here ]. So lets say I store some info like this: lyricLineInfo[0][0] = true; lyricLineInfo[0][1] = true; lyricLineInfo[0][2] = 0.0; lyricLineInfo[0][3] = 5.0; lyricLineInfo[0][4] = "First Line"; lyricLineInfo[1][0] = false; lyricLineInfo[1][1] = false; lyricLineInfo[1][2] = 5.0; lyricLineInfo[1][3] = 10.0; lyricLineInfo[1][4] = "Second Line"; How would I set the values like that in an ArrayList?

Comment: I'd hate to be a pain but again the original second index of my original array needs to stay at a constant 5 so instead of doing a 2D ArrayList I was looking for a 1D ArrayList with a 1D array with a max size of 5 inside.

Comment: Wait, does this make it two 1D arrays but not one 2D array? I mean if I were to set values to the line array (Referring to your edit 3) with the lyricLineInfo value set to 0 if I were to increase the value of lyricLineInfo to 1 then set new values for line inside of it would it replace the values assigned to line when lyricLineInfo's value is 0?

Comment: @clankfan1 - In Java, there's no such thing as a 2D array. There is only a 1D array of 1D arrays. In the example code, the string array at lyricLineInfo element 0 is independent of the string array at element 1. They can be changed independently.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand is there some way you could show me to to make this change to my code?

Comment: @clankfan1 - What do you want to do in your code that you don't understand how to do?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to use an array of String[] inside of my ArrayList and get it to work properly... Is there somewhere where I could post my code so you can see what excatly I'm trying to do?

Comment: @clankfan1 - Use an ArrayList<String[]> _instead_ of an array of String[].

Comment: I am using ArrayList<String[]> its just that I'm having a hard time getting values back mostly...

Comment: lyricLineInfo.get(1)[4] and lyricLineInfo.get(2)[4] return the same value and they're not suppose to seeing that they are set to two different values...

Comment: @clankfan1 - My guess is that you are inserting the same `String[]` array twice. Perhaps post the code you are using as a new question and the problem can be solved more quickly. Include the code used to insert values into the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.util.Vector<String[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList` like this:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

`ArrayList`s are flexible arrays in java. When you want to add something do this:

```
lyricLineInfo.add(stringToBeAdded, index) //for the first dimension and
lyricLineInfo.get(firstIndex).add(stringToBeAdded, index); //for the second dimension
```

Comment: this works in case you eventually need to expand the `5` as the second array size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List instead:

```
private List<String[]> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Then to add to the list you use:

```
lyricLineInfo.add(new String[5]);
```

and to get you do:

```
// Get the 3rd element (array index 2).
String[] strings = lyricLineInfo.get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you think about using Collections if you need an array with undefined size? :)

Comment: Hi MykoB, welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to be as specific with your answers as possible, especially if you suspect that the questioner is not already familiar with the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with an array, but you can use a List object. You could try something like this:

```
private List<String[]> lyricLineInfo = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

So then, assuming fieldLyrics.getText() returns a String[], you would do:

```
lyricLineInfo.add(fieldLyrics.getText());
```

Comment: The first dimension is the ArrayList - you can think of it as an array, except you access elements like nameOfList.get(3) instead of nameOfList[3]. Then, each element of the list or array is the fixed length String array, making the second dimension.

Comment: So can I use .set to set a value then? And also how would that work in 2d since I have the arraylist as 1d and an array as 1d?

Comment: Yes, you can use set() to replace an existing item in the list, and to add a new value to the end of the list, you can just use nameOfList.add(value). (See the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) doc for all the methods)  Think about what a 2-dimensional array (or list) is...It's an array of 1d arrays. Each element of the outer array is itself another array.

Answer (score 0):

If you only add new elements and iterate over all elements in list you should use `LinkedList` instead.

Collections are heavily used in Java. You should check [Java Collections Framework - tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)